# Possible typing error in the book

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

One of the side effects of learning on your own is to seriously doubt if the book has an error or your reasoning is incorrect. My book on multivariable calculus ([Rogawski 3rd Edition of Calculus Multivariable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1464186898)) has a problem at the end of Chapter 15:

> Let $g(u, v) = f(u^3-v^3, v^3 - u^3)$. Prove that, 
>   $$ v^2
>  \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} - u^2 \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} = 0
>  $$

I proceed as following:
Consider the functions $x(u, v) = u^3 - v^3$ and $y(u,v) = v^3 - u^3$. I can now say $g(u, v) = f(x, y)$. And therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
$$

Now,
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = 3u^2 \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = -3v^2 \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = -3u^2 \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = 3v^2
$$
Therefore,

\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = 3u^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - 3u^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\
\implies & \frac{1}{3u^2} \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\
& \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} = -3v^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + 3v^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\
\implies & \frac{1}{3v^2} \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{align}

Adding the two up I get $\displaystyle v^2\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} + u^2\frac{\partial g}{\partial v} = 0$ which is different from what I am asked to prove by a minus sign.

Am I wrong or is there a typing error in the book?

Comment: Which book are you referring to? Please [edit] the question to include the details.

Comment: Let's do an example.  Say $f(x,y)=y$.  in that case $g(u,v)=v^3-u^3$.  Then $\frac {\partial g}{\partial u}=-3u^2$ and $\frac {\partial g}{\partial v}=3v^2$.  The text then claims that $-3v^2u^2-(3u^2v^2)=0$ which is false.

Comment: General note:  as you surmise, math texts tend to have lots of typos and sometimes even deeper errors.  Keeps you on your toes.

Comment: Thanks @lulu. Your example pretty much answers my question. You should post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Shaun, edited as requested.